# Retrieve an array of objects using NSUserDefaults

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults

I have created a class called `student` and I am looking to use `NSUserDefaults` to store and retrieve an `array of student.`

```
//Establish array
var classonestudents = [student] ()
class student {
var name = String ()
var C4Role = 0
var LastTeam = 0
}
//This array is filled up by the user

//Store data
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(classonestudents, forKey: "class")

//Retrieve data
classonestudents = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("class")
```

I am getting the error :  `Cannot assign value of type 'AnyObject?' to type '[student]'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("class")` expects optional object of type `AnyObject`. You can force unwrap in `array of student.`

```
//Retrieve data
classonestudents = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("class") as! [student]
```

But you should always check if its nil :

```
if let students = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("class") as? [student]
{
    classonestudents = students
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just changing the last line of code with the following code will fix your error:

```
classonestudents = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("class") as! [student]
```

Hope, this will help you.